# How to do math function like 5log(7.5/2) in php?

Tags: php, math

I tried to do it like 5*log(7.5/2), but I think it's the wrong way, can anyone tell me how to do it right ?

Comment: You _think_ its the wrong way? Why?

Comment: the only problem I see here is, `7.5/2` which should be `5 * log(7.5, 2)`

Comment: cause I got example which tell a different answer. It's tell that 1+5log(5.7/2)=3.2742

but in my code result it's tell the answer is 6.2365949714028 

And now I get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, a base 10 logarithm is made using [`log10`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log10.php), not [`log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php) (which is for natural logarithm i.e. base *e*). Note also that your comparison example in the comments is with `5.7`, not `7.5`. Try this instead:

```
echo 1+5*log10(5.7/2);
```

Output:

```
3.2742243000426
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/AgeIp)